# i want to post different data types of various form field using axios interceptors in react

Tags: axios

```
const initialValue={
    bookname:"abc",
    description:"",
    sku:'',
    ISBN_ASIN_UPC:'',
    title:'',
    // image_upload:"",
    quantity:'',
    cost_price:'',
    profit:'',
    marketplace_commision:'',
    author:'',
    publisher:'',
    publication_date:'',
    volume:'',
    edition:'',
    item_condition:'',
    media:'',
    book_number:'',
    weight:'',
    length:'',
    width:'',
    height:''
  }

const [inventoryFormValue,setInventoryFormValue]=useState(initialValue)
  
const inventoryFormSubmit=async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(inventoryFormValue)
    // console.log("file",file)
    let response=await API.AddInventory(inventoryFormValue)
    console.log(response.data)
     if(response.data.status==="succes"){
      navigate("/bookCatalog")
     }
     
  
  }
```

I have taken form data from front end and store in a object in key value pair(i values are string but i want some integer also) i know all the integer will dyanamically behave as string whenever we have not defined as a integer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to typecast the string value to the integer where you know that for particular key the value should be number. Below is the way you can do that

```
let stringValue = '1';
console.log(typeof stringValue); // string
let convertedToNumber = +convertedToNumber; // this will convert string to number
console.log(typeof convertedToNumber);  // number
```

Note when you get value from form it will always be string so you would need to typecast it. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Actually my api is working fine in swaggar editor while connecting to front end it through an error like : error in response so what's the issue with axios interceptors

Comment: Can you provide full error which you getting?

Comment: ERROR IN RESPONSE:  {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', description: undefined, number: undefined, fileName: undefined, …}

Comment: code: "ERR_NETWORK"
columnNumber: undefinedconfig: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 20000, adapter: ƒ, …}
description: undefined
fileName: undefined
lineNumber: undefined
message: "Network Error"
name: "AxiosError"
number: undefined
stack: undefined
status: null
        
       Uncaught (in promise) Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}